# How can I hide staff-only frontend code from users?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm planning to use SvelteKit for a private control panel application. It will include functions for logged-in users, plus separate functions only for moderators and administrators.

Authentication for the backend API routes is straightforward. There will be no issues ensuring clients can only access the routes they are authorised to.

But I'm not clear on how I can protect the frontend routes. Ideally, I need for there to be no trace of the staff functionality in the frontend code that a user-level client has access to.

How can I accomplish this?

In the past I have used adapter-static with full static rendering (no node backend) and I don't think that will be suitable in this situation.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it could work to [disable client side rendering](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#csr) for your sensitive routes? That will seriously limit the functionality and worsen the experience on those routes though.

Comment: This is probably not really supported right now, especially with automatic code splitting it is hard to track which code is used where/how.

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally I need for there to be no trace of any of the staff functionality in the frontend code

You could create two separate SvelteKit projects: one for staff and one for users and host them on separate domains. Plus a third project which contains all the shared components and logic.

But that's a lot of work. So if this is not a hard requirement, I'd use a single SvelteKit project which includes the code for both users and staff.

> How I can protect the frontend routes.

In the page load functions you have the opportunity to [throw an error](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/errors) like a `401 Forbidden` or throw a login [redirect](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#redirects).

> using adapter-static

Still possible, but the "full static rendering" shouldn't render html pages that are behind authentication, so there'll be a lot more clientside-only routes.

Comment: I am doing this using adapter-static, I disabled  pre-rendering on sensitive pages and locked them behind a route guard. Even still, the client can never be trusted. I am of the belief that the backend should be secure since the frontend can be tampered with.